# MPIF90 running error "bad value during integer read"

Tags: fortran, mpi

There is a problem when I use the `mpif90` compiler that complains that 'bad value during integer read'. However, when I use the `gfortran` compiler, there is no problem.

The `gfortran` version is

```
program main
implicit none
character*100 :: line
integer :: ierr, i
open(10, file="test.txt", action="read")
read(10, '(A)' ,iostat=ierr) line
read(line, "(6X, I5)") i
print*, i
end program
```

The `mpif90` version is

```
program main
implicit none
include "mpif.h"
character*100 :: line
integer :: ierr, i, procID

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,procID,ierr)
if (procID==0) then
    open(10, file="test.txt", action="read")
    read(10, '(A)' ,iostat=ierr) line
    read(line, "(6X, I5)") i
    print*, i
endif
call mpi_finalize(ierr)
endprogram
```

the `test.txt` file contains that

```
TEST      1
```

1. The `gfortran` version gives correct answer `1`
2. `mpif90` version uses `mpif90` compiler to compile the program and use `mpirun -n 4 ./a.out` to run the program the outcome is

   > At line 12 of file read.f90
   >   Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read

Why there is such a problem? Can anyone fix this?

Comment: `mpif90` might be anything. It is just a wrapper around some compiler. Please tell use which compiler it is. What does `mpif90 -v` return? Which MPI library have you installed?

Comment: You are using `iostat=ierr`, but then you are not checking the value of `ierr`. You can't do that. Either remove the `iostat` or do check the value returned.

Comment: `mpif90 -v` returns that "mpifort for MPICH version 3.2
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)"

Comment: Thanks, I get it. I have used the `anaconda`'s mpif90 which cause such problem. After reinstall `MPICH`, the problem is fixed. But I don't understand why `anaconda`'s mpi could cause such problem.